# After Creating after update trigger i cant update any

Tags: mysql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Sales;

CREATE TABLE Sales (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    quantity INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    fiscalYear SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    fiscalMonth TINYINT NOT NULL,
    CHECK(fiscalMonth >= 1 AND fiscalMonth <= 12),
    CHECK(fiscalYear BETWEEN 2000 and 2050),
    CHECK (quantity >=0),
    UNIQUE(product, fiscalYear, fiscalMonth),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS log;

CREATE TABLE log (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
    text VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Triggers

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `sales_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `sales` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO log VALUES(NOW(),CONCAT('Update Student Record ', OLD.quantity));
END
```

> UPDATE `test for`.`sales` SET `quantity` = 36
> WHERE (`id` = 1);

> ERROR 1136: 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Iam new in mySQL Please help

Comment: `log` has 3 columns and your `INSERT` has two values. `INSERT INTO LOG(\`text\`) VALUES(CONCAT(...))`. This will let `timestamp` get its default value.

Comment: that is corret thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify columns in `INSERT` statement in your trigger explicitly, as you do not set all values in a row (auto incremented column excluded).

So it would be

`INSERT INTO log(timestamp, text) VALUES (NOW(),CONCAT('Update Student Record ', OLD.quantity));`

Comment: is it possible for many feild ?

Comment: As many as your table contains

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors.
First based on your trigger you need another column on log table which is as following

```
quantity INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Second , do not use [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) like text and timestamp, it is a bad practice. If you do please put it inside backticks

Third your insert statement should be

```
INSERT INTO log(`timestamp`,`text`,quantity) VALUES(NOW(),'Update Student Record', OLD.quantity);
```

there is no need for CONCAT.

Fourth,

```
`sales`
```

table is not the same as `Sales` table, because you have used backticks.

Full working trigger below:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE  TRIGGER `sales_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON Sales
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO log(`timestamp`,`text`,quantity) VALUES(NOW(),'Update Student Record', OLD.quantity);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Check working demo:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iqwShcHK3AGJvU4MDbxDku/0